# Confidence intervals for a curve with bootstrapping

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, nonlinear-regression

I am estimating `y= az + f(x)` in a semi-parametric way. I want to compute the standard error for the estimated coefficient for `a` and for each point in the nonparametric cruve `f(x)`. I am doing that by bootstrapping, i.e. by resampling with replacement (999 times), in order to obtain an empiric distribution of both `a` and `f(x)`.

How can I exactly find the confidence intervals (95%) for `f(x)`? Shall I go with `estimate + 2 sd(estimate)` where the s.d. (standard deviation) is obtained from the bootstrapped distribution of `f(x)` ? Or should I take the 0.975 and 0.025 percentile of the bootstrapped distribution of `f(x)`. If I go the latter case I get that the estimated curve is outside the confiedence bands both at the top and at the bottom of the distribution.

Comment: Is this intended to be a [pointwise interval or a simultaneous interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_and_prediction_bands)?

Comment: If I understand properly, the difference between the two options concerns that in the pointwise I care about the c.i. for each `z_i`by itself, while in the simultaneous case I care about the c.i. for all the `z_i` taken together. I was reasoning in terms of pointwise interval. However any suggestion with value added is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I would appreciate if you may also kindly provide me some (also one) references on the topic.